# How do I delete an attachment for a Rally task

Tags: task, attachment, rally

How do I delete an attachment for a Rally task?

It's easy enough to create the attachment (drag & drop), but I don't personally see *any way to delete it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the task, then select 'Edit...' from the 'Actions' pull-down.
To the far right of the attachment name, there is a trash-can icon.
Click on it to delete the attachment.
Then click 'Save & Close'.

For example:

Original UI interface:
[image]

New UI interface:
[image]

Comment: This must be browser-dependent or version of rally dependent or something.  I am already editing when I open the task, and there is no "trash-can" icon; the gear icon has bulk-actions, but the only one there is download, not delete.

Comment: @JosephDoggie JPKole gave the correct answer. If you check the checkbox to the left it will provide you with only bulk action items and in this case "download". If you leave it unchecked, it will give you individual action items "download" and "delete".

Comment: yes that worked, but it is really subtle interface, the folks at Rally do need to fix this somehow....

Comment: I just looked up my own post on this (LOL).  It is really subtle, one must NOT check the file name's checkbox, as one might suppose!